# Create a UIViewController class instance from string (view controller string name) without using Storyboards or NIB/XIB?

Tags: ios, swift, class, viewcontroller, identifier

I wanted to instantiate view controllers from push notifications, most tutorials seem to suggest passing the identifier for the VC and matching them up with the storyboardID.

Issue is my app is made programatically and so I cant add storyboard identifiers.

How can i resolve this programatically so i can reference a VC via a string?

Update:

My point is that if the notification parses a string of what VC to instantiate e.g. "Deashboard" i cant then load via identifier that matches that string, id need a massive switch statement for every possibility that then runs your code in each case

Comment: Do you have storyboard (no segue connection) for your view controller design?

Comment: no its all programatic

Comment: "so i can reference a VC " And how do you init it? You don't have to use a storyboardID, you can do `MyVCForPush *vc = [[MyVCForPush alloc] init]`; `MyVCForPush *vc =  [[MyVCForPush alloc] initWithXibName:@someName]`, then `[vc setPushInfo:myPushInfo]`, and then present it.

Comment: @jackdm declare push notification constants with names of viewController in a constant file ..then you don't have to do anything .. you dnt have to use switch statement ..

Answer (score 2):

When a view controller is not associated with storybaord or nib file, it's (class's) default initiazer provides an instance of view controller.

Try this and See:

**Objective-C**

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:true];
```

**Swift**

```
let viewController = ViewController()
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

**Update**

To convert your string class name into view controller, try following extension.

```
extension NSObject {

    func viewControllerFromString(viewControllerName: String) -> UIViewController? {

        if let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
            print("CFBundleName - \(appName)")
            if let viewControllerType = NSClassFromString("\(appName).\(viewControllerName)") as? UIViewController.Type {
                return viewControllerType.init()
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

}
```

Now, get your view controller from class string

```
if let viewController = viewControllerFromString(viewControllerName: "ViewController") as? ViewController {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Similar functionality with String extension:

```
extension String {

    func getViewController() -> UIViewController? {

        if let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
            print("CFBundleName - \(appName)")
            if let viewControllerType = NSClassFromString("\(appName).\(self)") as? UIViewController.Type {
                return viewControllerType.init()
            }
        }

        return nil
    }

}


if let viewController = "ViewController".getViewController() as? ViewController {
   navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: yeah this is what i do, but my point is that if the notification parses a string of what VC to instantiate e.g. "Deashboard" i cant then load via identifier that matches that string, id need a massive switch statement for every possibility that then runs your code in each case

Comment: @Krunal what is this CFBundleName? From where it comes?

Comment: @Krunal getting nil

Comment: @ArgaPK - Try to print `Bundle.main.infoDictionary` and see. You'll get what you want.   `print("Bundle.main.infoDictionary - \(Bundle.main.infoDictionary)")`

Comment: @Krunal getViewController() is returning Nil , y?

Comment: @ArgaPK simply execute this code and share output - print("Bundle.main.infoDictionary - \(Bundle.main.infoDictionary)")

Comment: @Krunal print Bundle.main.infoDictionary is printing all the information but the method is not working.

Comment: Your method is returning nil , y?i am using extension String

Comment: @ArgaPK - share me that printing log. I'll help you to find out what should you do to get come value.

Answer (score 0):

Add Extension to `String`:

```
extension String {
    public func getViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        if let appName = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleName"] as? String {
            if let viewControllerType = Bundle.main.classNamed("\(appName).\(self)") as? UIViewController.Type {
                return viewControllerType.init()
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let className = "CustomViewController"
if let controller = className.getViewController() {
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}
```